# Find the first day of specific years ago from current day using lubridate package

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I'm able to find the date certain years ago from today with code below:

```
library(lubridate)
today <- format(Sys.Date())
pre_3years <- ymd(today) - years(3)
pre_3years
```

Out:

```
[1] "2018-12-27"
```

In fact, I hope to get the first day of `pre_3year`, which is `2018-01-01` for this example, how could I get that using `lubridate` package in R? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `floor_date` from `lubridate` to get 1st day of the year.

```
library(lubridate)
first_day_of_n_prev <- function(x) {
  floor_date(Sys.Date() - years(x), 'year')  
}

first_day_of_n_prev(3)
#[1] "2018-01-01"

first_day_of_n_prev(2)
#[1] "2019-01-01"
```

Comment: Thanks, `floor_date()` is the function I'm looking for. Also, you convert my code to a function, which is awesome.